# Gmail authentication using Oauth2 issue

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api

In my C# project I am using Oauth 2 for Gmail account authentication. I came across one scenario in which the requested token can be successfully obtained using other user email account. I am requesting access token for **user1@gmail.com**

```
GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(ClientSecret,scopes,user1@gmail.com,
                                    CancellationToken.None,objFileDataStore).Result;
```

The above request will open the web browser for log in to gmail account to which we need permission. If I log in to another gmail user **(user2@gmail.com)** It will successfully returns the access token without any error. How can we check if the same gmail user has provided the permission for the application.

Thanks in advance.

Mayuresh

Comment: If you don't want to prompt user every time they login even though they authorized your app already, use "offline access". If the consent screen is not prompted for a user, that means user has already provided the permission.

Comment: My question is not about asking permission for every time. I am trying to authorize user1 through my app but user is logged in to user2@gmail.com in web browser and allow access.